# SSIS unable to swap out any buffers to relive memory pressure

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms, etl

I've got a hefty etl process that's currently maxing out a server with 64 gigs of memory. I have ssms set to limit to 56 gigs to leave room for other processes, and I've set up BLOBTempStoragePath and BufferTempStoragePath to point to different memory locations on the same server. I've maxed out the default buffer size as well.

The process is a single package that pulls and merges from two sources, and either updates or inserts a row into a target database after checking for changes to each row in the source.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing or if there's a way to avoid these out of memory exceptions? I'm kinda thinking that at this point I might just have to rework the entire process.

Comment: How are you updating - using OLE DB Command or staging updates to a table? What data types are coming across? Is there a reason you're using a merge? Sorted data is a prerequisite for the Merge Join component - are you sorting within the data flow or did you sort within the source systems (assuming that was available)?

Comment: With `SSMS set to limit to 56 gigs` you mean the SQL Server itself I assume?

Comment: Updateding using OLE DB commands, data types are mostly varchar with a few datetimes. Date is hitting the merge sorted already. Sorting within the query that pulls data so, in theory, it should be sorted before it hits the merge. And the sql server has 64 gigs of ram but I'm having ssms max out at 56 of that 64.